# Getting few records with subscriberid in _subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

Can you please advise what is wrong on my query where I am getting very few records with subscriberid coming from _subscribers dataview.

```
SELECT 
  EmailAddress as 'EMAIL_ADDR'
, SubscriberID
, Status
, DateUndeliverable
, DateUnsubscribed
, DateJoined
, BounceCount
, Domain
, SubscriberKey
, SubscriberType
, Locale
FROM _Subscribers
WHERE EmailAddress IN
  (
  SELECT EMAIL_ADDR 
  FROM ACTIVE_AUDIENCE
  )
```

Comment: Is this in a child Business Unit or in the parent? You might need to add the 'ent.' prefix to your dataview to grab the correct data. e.g. `ent._Subscribers`

Comment: thank you - it works with ent.subscribers. When to use ent._subscribers vs _subscribers? Does _open, clicks, sent needs also to have ent.?

Comment: added an answer with more details

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a child account to look up subscribers, you will need to use the `ent.` prefix on it. This will allow you to look up via the account (parent) data view instead of the BU specific DV.

> If your account is a child account in an Enterprise, you can query
>   data extensions in your parent account. Prefix the data extension name
>   in the query with ENT.

Taken from the [SFMC documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm&type=5) (this is specific to a DE, but also applies to the BUs)

`_Subscribers` is a special case where to make it mimic 'All Subscribers' you need to utilize the ent prefix.

The DVs that are specific to BU and require the `ent.` prefix to get the parent level information are `_Bounce`, `_Click`, `_Open`, `_FTAF` and `_Unsubscribes`.

For the above listed DataViews, you only need to use `ent` if you want to include sends/clicks/etc that happened in the parent BU. This will then not include those in the BU you are querying from.

So basically: `SELECT * FROM ent._Sent` will return only the sends from the parent BU, where `SELECT * FROM _Sent` will select the sends from the BU you are querying from.

> Enterprise level data views don't include sends, opens, clicks,
>   unsubscribes, Forward To A Friend data, and bounces. You can find this
>   data by querying data views in the sender's Marketing Cloud account.

Taken from the [SFMC documentation on DataViews](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_views.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `JOIN` instead of a nested `Select`

```
FROM _Subscribers s
INNER JOIN ACTIVE_AUDIENCE a ON s.EMAIL_ADDR = a.EMAIL_ADDR
```